# Search only all the nodes that have tags

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to execute queries in Overpass Turbo looking for only nodes that contain a tag definition,

for example i'm running a query like this:

```
<osm-script output="json">
 <query type="node">
  <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
 </query>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton"/>
</osm-script>
```

this return all nodes with and without tags,

how to query only nodes with tags?

Comment: Question was answered here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044875/overpass-api-requesting-any-node-that-has-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Overpass-Turbo query returns all nodes with an osm-tag in your selected bbox:

```
node({{bbox}})[~"."~"."];
out meta;
```